# apache redirect http to https doesn't work with safari and chrome ios

Tags: apache, ipad, https

i have apache installed on server with ssl certificate applied with conf file and this redirection setup:

`RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycare123\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^ https://www.mycare123.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
Redirects works in
windows
ios chrome
however not in
ios ipad chrome,safari
ios safari .
Just keeps spinning until it says server stopped responding.

If i eneterd full https variant of the URL it works.
this is access log
`GET /wp-content/themes/mc/js/modernizr-3.7.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5617 "https://www.mycare123.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) App$`

This is TLS 1.3, searched but found no answer.
my domain is [www.mycare123.com](http://www.mycare123.com)

Comment: There is no immediate reason why a browser on a specific device should show a different behavior. So you will have to dig deeper yourself into your setup: does that browser on the iPad offer a developer console? If so, what do you see inside the networking tab? And what do your http server's access and error log files show?

Comment: check the domain www.mycare123.com

Comment: no server access or error log events appear

Comment: The only explanation for you _not_ receiving any log entries is that your iPad never sends any requests to your server. So you are most likely looking at client side cached results.

Comment: after rechecking  access log
`GET /wp-content/themes/mc/js/modernizr-3.7.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5617 "https://www.mycare123.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) App$
`

Comment: Np i found this problem also on safari desktop ios...console on safari didnt reaveal anything....cleared cache still the same

Answer (score 0):

the problem was local in ipad chrome and safaro and pc safari that clearing cashe didnt solve it